# dispatch_after in swift explanation

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am currently working on a project and for a part of it I need to unhighlight a button after a set period of time. I decided to use `dispatch_after`.

I have managed to get it working, but can someone please explain me how this line of code exactly works? I have been unable to understand how `dispatch_after` exactly works.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1000 * Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                self.redButton.highlighted = false

            }
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more in-depth, step by step explanation.

Comment: I dont understand what `Dispatch_time_now` and `dispatch_get_main_queue` mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's break it down into multiple statements:

```
let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1000 * Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC)))
let queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

dispatch_after(when, queue) {
    self.redButton.highlighted = false
}
```

`dispatch_after()` enqueues the block for execution at a certain time
on a certain queue. In your case, the queue is the "main queue"
which is "the serial dispatch queue associated with the application’s main thread". All UI elements must be modified on the main thread only.

The `when:` parameter of `dispatch_after()` is a `dispatch_time_t`
which is documented as "a somewhat abstract representation of time".
`dispatch_time()` is an utility function to compute that time value.
It takes an initial time, in this case `DISPATCH_TIME_NOW` which 
"indicates a time that occurs immediately", and adds an offset which
is specified in nanoseconds:

```
let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1000 * Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC)))
```

`NSEC_PER_MSEC = 1000000` is the number of nanoseconds per millisecond,
so

```
Int64(1000 * Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC))
```

is an offset of 1000*1000000 nanoseconds = 1000 milliseconds = one second.

The explicit type conversions are necessary because Swift does not
implicitly convert between types. Using `Double` ensures that it
works also in cases like

```
let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
```

to specify an offset of 0.3 seconds.

*Summary:* Your code enqueues a block to be executed on the main
thread in 1000 ms from now.

*Update:* See [How do I write dispatch_after GCD in Swift 3 and 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3-and-4) for how the syntax changed
in Swift 3.