# How do I write dispatch_after GCD in Swift 3, 4, and 5?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

In Swift 2, I was able to use `dispatch_after` to delay an action using grand central dispatch:

```
var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) 
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
    // your function here 
})
```

But this no longer seems to compile since Swift 3. What is the preferred way to write this in modern Swift?

Comment: Further information about the migration process can be found here: [https://swift.org/migration-guide/](https://swift.org/migration-guide/) The section "Dispatch" is the relevant for this question

Comment: should your question be `UInt64`?

Answer (score 1189, accepted):

The syntax is simply:

```
// to run something in 0.1 seconds

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    // your code here
}
```

---

Note, the above syntax of adding `seconds` as a `Double` seems to be a source of confusion (esp since we were accustomed to adding nsec). That “add seconds as `Double`” syntax works because `deadline` is a `DispatchTime` and, behind the scenes, there is a `+` operator that will take a `Double` and add that many seconds to the `DispatchTime`:

```
public func +(time: DispatchTime, seconds: Double) -> DispatchTime
```

But, if you really want to add an integer number of msec, μs, or nsec to the `DispatchTime`, you can also add a `DispatchTimeInterval` to a `DispatchTime`. That means you can do:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500)) {
    // 500 msec, i.e. 0.5 seconds
    …
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .microseconds(1_000_000)) {
    // 1m microseconds, i.e. 1 second
    …
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .nanoseconds(1_500_000_000)) {
    // 1.5b nanoseconds, i.e. 1.5 seconds
    …
}
```

These all seamlessly work because of this separate overload method for the `+` operator in the `DispatchTime` class.

```
public func +(time: DispatchTime, interval: DispatchTimeInterval) -> DispatchTime
```

---

It was asked how one goes about canceling a dispatched task. To do this, use `DispatchWorkItem`. For example, this starts a task that will fire in five seconds, or if the view controller is dismissed and deallocated, its `deinit` will cancel the task:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var item: DispatchWorkItem?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        item = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
            self?.doSomething()
            self?.item = nil
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: item!)
    }

    deinit {
        item?.cancel()
    }
    
    func doSomething() { … }
}
```

Note the use of the `[weak self]` capture list in the `DispatchWorkItem`. This is essential to avoid a strong reference cycle. Also note that this does not do a preemptive cancelation, but rather just stops the task from starting if it hasn’t already. But if it has already started by the time it encounters the `cancel()` call, the block will finish its execution (unless you’re manually checking `isCancelled` inside the block).

---

#### Swift concurrency

While the original question was about the old GCD `dispatch_after` vs. the newer `asyncAfter` API, this raises the question of how to achieve the same behavior in the newer Swift concurrency and its `async`-`await`. As of iOS 16 and macOS 13 we would prefer [`Task.sleep(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:)):

```swift
try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))        // 2 seconds
…
```

Or

```swift
try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(200)) // 0.2 seconds
…
```

Or if we need to support back to iOS 13 and macOS 10.15, we would use [`Task.sleep(nanoseconds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(nanoseconds:)) instead.

And to support cancelation, save a `Task`:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var task: Task<Void, Error>?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        task = Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
            await doSomething()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        task?.cancel()
    }

    func doSomething() async { … }
}
```

Or in SwiftUI, we might use the [`.task {…}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier, which “will automatically cancel the task at some point after the view disappears before the action completes.” We do not even need to save the `Task` to manually cancel later.

We should recognize that before we had Swift concurrency, calling any `sleep` function used to be an anti-pattern, one that we would studiously avoid, because it would block the current thread. That was a serious error when done from the main thread, but even was problematic when used in background threads as the GCD worker thread pool is so limited. But the new [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:)) functions do *not* block the current thread, and are therefore safe to use from any actor (including the main actor).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and in fact https://swift.org/migration-guide/ mentions the need to make that change by hand.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's way too late here :). Thought that all the mess should go actually, but didn't take the leap. IMO the "simple" solution is the-one-true-solution.

Comment: @Rob how would I go about canceling it? Thanks.

Comment: Ok so how do you add a dynamic wait? For example, I have a let number : Float = 1.0. And .now() + .milliseconds(number) doesn't work. Nor does Double(number). I can't figure it out.

Comment: The `DispatchTimeInterval` renditions, like `.milliseconds` require `Int`. But if just adding seconds, I'd use `Double`, e.g. `let n: Double = 1.0; queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + n) { ... }`.

Comment: Here, 5 is in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: @JayprakashDubey - If you say `.now() + 5`, that’s five seconds. If you want Anything other than seconds, (e.g. millseconds or nanoseconds or anything else), you have to explicitly qualify it (e.g. `.now() + .milliseconds(5)`).

Answer (score 131):

**Swift 4:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {
   // Code
}
```

For the time `.seconds(Int)`, `.microseconds(Int)` and `.nanoseconds(Int)` may also be used.

Comment: `.milliseconds` is better than Double.

Comment: Very nice. A note for others: you can also use any of the other `DispatchTimeInterval` enum values too.
`case seconds(Int)` 
`case milliseconds(Int)`
`case microseconds(Int)`
`case nanoseconds(Int)`

Comment: @RobMacEachern, thanks that´s a good suggestion I add it to the answer.

Comment: `.milliseconds is better than Double. ` -- I want that on a T-shirt ;).

Answer (score 63):

If you just want the delay function in

**Swift 4 & 5**

```
func delay(interval: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + interval) {
          closure()
     }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
delay(interval: 1) { 
    print("Hi!")
}
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: ) does not work. It says it does not overload any method from its superclass.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: closure)` is simpler.

Answer (score 16):

after Swift 3 release, also the @escaping has to be added

```
func delay(_ delay: Double, closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
    closure()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

You can create a extension on DispatchQueue and add function delay which uses `DispatchQueue` asyncAfter function internally

```
extension DispatchQueue {
   static func delay(_ delay: DispatchTimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: closure)
   }
}
```

and use

```
DispatchQueue.delay(.milliseconds(10)) {
   print("task to be done")
}
```

Comment: How is this different from @rockdaswift’s answer?

Comment: as I mentioned it wraps asyncAfter inside performAfter function which takes delay as parameter and it can be easier to call using just performAfter(delay: 2) { }

Comment: Closure parameters are non-escaping by default,  @escaping indicate that a closure parameter may escape. added @ escaping parameter in closure to save potential crash.

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat different flavour of the Accepted Answer.

**Swift 4**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1 + .milliseconds(500) + 
.microseconds(500) + .nanoseconds(1000)) {
                print("Delayed by 0.1 second + 500 milliseconds + 500 microseconds + 
                      1000 nanoseconds)")
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

call `DispatchQueue.main.after(when: DispatchTime, execute: () -> Void)`

I'd highly recommend using the Xcode tools to convert to Swift 3 (Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax). It caught this for me

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5 and above**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
   // code to execute                 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers mentioned running on a non-main thread, so adding my 2 cents.

On **main queue** (main thread)

```
let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(10)
mainQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
    // ...
}
```

OR

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(10)) { 
    // ...
}
```

On **global queue** (non main thread, based on QOS specified) .

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(100)
backgroundQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline, qos: .background) { 
    // ...
}
```

OR

```
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(100), qos: .background) {
    // ...
}
```