# How to call a function within the function below after the first has done from a timer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here is my flow in simple form. I still need to call decisionMaker() when finished after #2 is finished running do to the time is up and take the global variable for the measurements to decisionmaker() for the case test

TestButtonTAPPED() and calls:

1. recordTimer()
2. gatherInput()
3. selector: levelTimerCallback()
4. decisionMaker()

   ```
   // 1.
   func recordTimer() {
       /* After 10 seconds, let's stop the recording process */
       let delayInSeconds = 10.0
       let delayInNanoSeconds = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

       DispatchQueue.main.after(when: delayInNanoSeconds, execute: {
           self.soundRecorder!.stop()
           self.handBtn.isHidden = false
       })

   }

   // 2.
   func gatherInput() {
       levelTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.9, target: self, selector: #selector(DBListener.levelTimerCallback), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
   }

   //3.
   func levelTimerCallback() {
       if soundRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0) > -30
       {
           // Do gathering for vaiables
       }
   }


   // 4.
   func decisionMaker() {
       // case statments here for final measurement
   }



   @IBAction func handTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

       clearGlobalVariablesOnTap()
       listner()
       soundRecorder.record()
       recordTimer()
       dbListener.gatherInput()

   }
   ```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve :)

Comment: @Asdrubal  I want #2 to call #4 when #2 is finished with its time

Comment: Why can't you just call `decisionMaker()` in the if statement in #3 method?

Comment: @Asdrubal   #2 calls #3 several times in the time frame. I need when #2 time is up then to call #4

Comment: couldn't you use something like dispatch_after when you start the call for #2 or use a completion handler when you start the call for #2

Comment: @james based on the code you provided above you your timer doesn't stop it just calls levelTimerCallback every 0.9 seconds. So can you  provide some code to show when levelTimer stops? Because you have repeat: true so it will just keep repeating and every stop running? If you could provide more code that might help

Comment: That is how I have it and it stops.?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3 ... also Go Green?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog that is why I am asking, I am not familiar with the dispatch_after to trailing closure. I looked up close but still confused (lol). I will look up dispatch_after I guess... :)

Comment: @james where are you calling `gatherInput()`?

Comment: @Asdrubal - thanks looking at that post now :)

Comment: @IBAction func handTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        clearGlobalVariablesOnTap()
        listner()
        soundRecorder.record()
        recordTimer()
        dbListener.gatherInput()
       
    }

Comment: @Asdrubal has a good point, your levelTimer is on repeat and if it stops, then you must call levelTimer.invalidate somewhere in your app.  If that is the case, then that is the point when you would want to perform the action for #2 being finished.. also mississippi state bulldogs! #HailState

Comment: @james Please see my answer below and leave a comment if I didn't understand your question correctly. MSU_Bulldog I figured you weren't  michigan state based on the bulldog part. But you never know lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func handTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    clearGlobalVariablesOnTap()
    listner()
    soundRecorder.record()
    recordTimer()
}

func recordTimer() {

    //As soon as this method is called this portion will get executed
    dbListener.gatherInput()

    /* After 10 seconds, let's stop the recording process */
    let delay = 10.0
    let delayInSeconds = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(delay)


    //After 10 seconds this block will execute
    DispatchQueue.main.after(when: delayInSeconds, execute: {
        self.soundRecorder!.stop()
        self.handBtn.isHidden = false
        self.levelTimer.invalidate = true
        self.decisionMaker()
    })

}

func gatherInput() {
    levelTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.9, target: self, selector: #selector(DBListener.levelTimerCallback), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)
}

func levelTimerCallback() {
    if soundRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0) > -30
    {
        // Do gathering for vaiables
    }
}


func decisionMaker() {
    // case statments here for final measurement
}
```

Comment: No problem. Happy Coding

Comment: of course code 8 yells at me now - back to converting to swift 3