# Is it possible to block execution of my code until UIAlertController is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

is there anyway to wait the user to press the button that dismiss the alertController in swift 3, by using DispatchQueue or something else?

Comment: Take a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3

Comment: yes i kow about it, but i mean, after i presented  the alertcontroller, is there anyway to wait (to make my code execute nothing ) till the user dismiss the alert ?

Comment: If you want to stop the execution of your code till user dismiss alert then add your execution code in `UIAlertAction`'s handler part.

Comment: @NiravD in fact, i add a normal button to the alert in order to dismiss it, so  how could i add the handler to stop the  execution of my code till user press this button ?

Comment: Put all your code that you want to execute later on that action handler.

Comment: @NiravD i couldn't put the next lines of code in the action handler for many reasons, but i need to execute them after the pressing of the button, because right now, these lines are executed directly after the showing of the alertcontroller

Comment: @Anthony Then Make one function and put all that code inside function that you want to execute later and simply call that function in the action handler part.

Comment: @NiravD i'm still thinking about something like that :  self.present(self.alertController, animated: true, completion : { () -> Void in ,and to make the dismiss inside of it,  but it doesn't work,

Comment: @Anthony Are you getting now?

Answer (score 2):

Just move all the code you want to execute after the alert is dismissed into a separate method. When you're adding `UIAlertActions`, make all the actions' `handler` parameter call that method. This way, whichever button the user presses, your code will always be executed!

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
alertController.displayAndWaitUntilDismissed()
// This line is only reached after the alert controller is dismissed
print("Alert controller dismissed.")
```

Theoretically, yes, you could use a dispatch semaphore to block until the alert is dismissed. But it’s a bad idea – I can’t even think of a scenario where it would be acceptable. Simply accept that you have to deal with it asynchronously, by executing the desired code in the alert controller action.

Answer (score -1):

You MUST NOT block the main thread and waiting for dismissing your alert so the only way is doing this asynchronously.

For instance you can use next common approach with `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`:

```swift
fileprivate var AssociatedObjectKey: UInt8 = 0

extension UIAlertController : UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    
    var onDissmiss: (() -> Void)? {
        set {
            transitioningDelegate = newValue != nil ? self : nil
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectKey) as? (() -> Void)
        }
    }

    
    public func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        onDissmiss?()
        return nil
    }
}
```

How to use:

```swift
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)

let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
alert.addAction(ok)

alert.onDissmiss = {
    print("dissmiss")
}

present(alert, animated: true)
```