# How does DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) work in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-after

In Swift 3 the syntax of GCD has changed quite a bit.

A call to dispatch_after() now looks like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {//do something}
```

That code would invoke the block 5 seconds after it's called.

How does that work? The docs say that the deadline parameter is a `dispatch_time_t`, which is a typealias for UInt64. I assume it's a mach time in nanoseconds. However, the `.now() + delay` syntax is adding decimal seconds to the value. Doesn't DispatchTime.now() return a UInt64 ? If so, adding decimal seconds to that should not work. If anything, I would expect the value added to `.now()` to be treated as nanoseconds, which would not be very useful.

(In swift 2 you used to have to multiply the value by a constant for the number of nanoseconds per second.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the answer to my own question in this thread:

[How do I write dispatch_after GCD in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3)

Apparently there is an override of the `+` operator that takes a `DispatchTime` and a double, treats the double as decimal seconds, and returns a resulting `DispatchTime`.

Comment: If you command-click on the `+` in Xcode then you'll see the declaration.

Comment: @MartinR,  thanks for the suggestion. In order to do that it would have had to occur to me that it was an override of the `+` operator that was doing it.

Comment: It seems to me we need a form of this call that takes a delay value, not a time relative to the current Mach time, since that's likely the most common form used by application developers. It would be a pretty simple extension, but it should be built in.