# Swift - How to add a delay for vibrate

Tags: ios, swift, vibration

I use this code inside my motionBegan function. And when i shake my device it vibrates. Is there a way to add a delay so vibration begins after 1 second later for example?

```
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

Comment: Put it in a Dispatch with delay

Comment: You may find this link useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GCD `dispatch_after`. (The easiest way is with my `delay` function, shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994.)

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Yes it does. I've included a version of the `delay` function adapted for Swift 3. DispatchQueue's `after` is still `dispatch_after` in disguise, anyway!

Comment: @matt is absolutely right.  Do note that Apple has unified the dispatch API's to make them more natural in Swift 3.  If you're using Swift 3 and up, you should switch to the new `DispatchQueue` syntax I showed in my answer.  It does exactly the same thing but it's the right API to use moving forward.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3 and up, use a `DispatchQueue`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(.now() + 1.0) {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
}
```