# Asynchronous Swift processing in Linux not working

Tags: swift, linux, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, swift4

I'm trying to understand how Swift 4.0 asynchronous processing works in Linux.

After looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) and some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3-and-4) on SO I came up with this simple example:

```
import Dispatch
import Glibc

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
    print("Done!")
}

print("Sleeping for 2 seconds...")
usleep(2 * 1_000_000)

print("Exiting...")
```

However, this only prints:

```
Sleeping for 2 seconds...
Exiting...
```

Why does it not print `Done!`? What am I missing? How do I write a simple parallel processing example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was using the `main` queue. If I instead create a new queue, it works as expected.

```
import Dispatch
import Glibc

DispatchQueue(label: "worker").asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
    print("Doing work...")
    usleep(1 * 1_000_000)
    print("Work done")
}

print("Sleeping for 2 seconds...")
usleep(2 * 1_000_000)

print("Exiting...")
```

Prints out the expected result:

```
Sleeping for 2 seconds...
Doing work...
Work done!
Exiting...
```

Comment: Try `asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4)` ... that will never be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call [`dispatchMain()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452860-dispatchmain) to start the GCD event loop:

> Executes blocks submitted to the main queue

Example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    print("Done!")
    exit(0)
}

print("Starting main event loop...")
dispatchMain()
```

Comment: Where should I add it in my example above? If I add it after `.asyncAfter{...}`, it prints "Done!", but then does not continue executing other statements and doesn't print "Sleeping..." or "Exiting...".

Comment: @naktinis: That is correct, dispatchMain never returns. You have to `exit(0)` the program somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch is not preemptive.  Blocks that are submitted to a non-concurrent queue will be processed in order, and no block will be processed until the block before them finishes.  You put your block on the `main` queue, which corresponds to the main thread, however, the main thread is busy sleeping until it exits, and never has a chance to do dispatch queue work.

Martin R mentioned `dispatchMain`, though another option would be [`RunLoop.main.run(mode: .defaultRunLoopMode, before: .distantFuture)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1411525-run), which would only run the runloop once, allowing the program to exit afterwards.