# How to add a variable's integer to another variable's integer

Tags: swift, arc4random

I'm trying to add `randomAmountOfTime` to `DispatchTime.now()` but it gives me an error.

Error:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DispatchTime' and 'Int'

Here's what I did:

```
var randomAmountOfTime = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
let when = DispatchTime.now() + randomAmountOfTime
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatch Time is Floating point number, therefore you must pass Double type or DispatchTime as provided by @rmaddy. Swift cannot add together Int and DispatchTime (because there is no operator provided in DispatchTime, you could create your custom extension). The same goes for Float and DispatchTime - the methods for some reason aren't available in the private API.

This should do:

```
var randomAmountOfTime = Double(arc4random_uniform(5))

let when = DispatchTime.now() + randomAmountOfTime
```

for further understanding you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3-and-4)

Edit:

You could create your custom file (like DispatchTime+Int.swift) and create custom operator for Adding together Int and DispatchTime:

```
  public func + (left: Int, right: DispatchTime) -> DispatchTime {
    return Double(left) + right
}
```

Comment: In this case it would be simpler to cast `arc4random_uniform(5)` to `Double` instead of `Int` then you can add it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `randomAmountOfTime` is seconds, you can use `DispatchTimeInterval.seconds`.

```
var randomAmountOfTime = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))
let when = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(randomAmountOfTime)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the first one seems more simple than your answer. Thank you for the help anyways!