# Pass DispatchTime as an argument in DispatchAfter

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

There is some old code I am processing. Following are two lines (old code) which I am not able to convert or rather understand :

```
let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DispatchTime.now()), Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))  
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
```

Now, to make it work in **Swift 4.x**, this is what I did for **line 1** :

```
let dispatchTime =  DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: UInt64(Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))))
```

I made this conversion on the basis of initialiser description as mentioned [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime) :

> Creates a time relative to the system clock that ticks since boot.

Since they say that it creates a *relative time*, `DispatchTime.now()` is already considered. Not to mention, I might be wrong. Please do correct me.

For the second line, I am unaware as to how to pass `DispatchTime` as an argument in `DispatchAfter`.

Comment: This didnt help you ??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3-and-4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you want in Swift 3+:

```
let seconds = 2.0
// dispatchTime 2 seconds from now:
let dispatchTime: DispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + seconds
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
    // code to be executed
}
```

Comment: So where does DispatchTime comes into picture - in the new syntax ?

Comment: Makes much sense now.