# Delay calls using DispatchQueue.asyncAfter

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I've been trying to understand how the `asyncAfter` method works in `DispatchQueue` so I could implement it in my code to delay network calls. I've tried the suggestions from this thread to no avail:
[How do I write dispatch_after GCD in Swift 3 and 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801436/how-do-i-write-dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift-3-and-4)

In my test code only the first print statement gets printed. How come the second print doesn't print?

```
func queueWithDelay() {
    let delayQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "testqueue")

    print("First: \(Date())")

    delayQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
        print("Second: \(Date())")
    }
}
queueWithDelay()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you running this in a playground?

Comment: Yes, it's playground. The duplicate link solved the problem. Thanks!